# How to create listview items in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

Reading offical [Xamarin documentation about listview](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/), you create template in xaml (xml file) and fill listView items programably in code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:constants="clr-
 namespace:XamarinFormsSample;assembly=XamarinFormsXamlSample"
 x:Class="XamarinFormsXamlSample.Views.EmployeeListPage"
 Title="Employee List">
   <ListView x:Name="EmployeeView">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <TextCell Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
 </ContentPage>
```

And then you fill items in code like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

public EmployeeListPage()
{
  // just for demonstration purposes
  employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayName="Rob Finnerty"});
  employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayName="Bill Wrestler"});

  //defined in XAML to follow
  EmployeeView.ItemsSource = employees;
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to define items in xaml? I'm setting up a simple settings page and would like to add items in xml. I ended up using [TableView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/), but am still curious if it can be done?

Comment: I believe, design(View) should be decoupled with the DataAccess(Model).. I recommend you to follow the steps what you did even if it a simple settings page.

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu yes I also like to decouple things and you are corret, but I'm just curious if it can be done (although we are moving away from good practises). Another thing is that, TableView can consist of different types of cells (e.g. TextCell, EntryCell, custom cell ...).

Answer (score 3):

You can define ListView.Items and place some other WPF controls in there.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Items>
        <Label Content="123"/>
        <TextBox Text="ABC"/>
        <CheckBox Checked="True"/>
    </ListView.Items>                    
</ListView>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Error: 'Cannot assign property Items'. Perhpas I missed something. I just places above code to xaml/xml file as ContentPage child.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the ItemSource in the xaml by putting the list items inside of some kind of ObservableCollection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:UserApp.Models"
             x:Class="UserApp.Interface.SettingsPage"
             Title="Settings">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <col:ArrayList>
                <models:Employee DisplayName="Rob Finnerty" />
                <models:Employee DisplayName="Bill Wrestler" />
            </col:ArrayList>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

You can also use `<x:String>text</x:String>` instead of objects by removing the property name from the binding.